# I get this "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (220,)" with padua function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am using a function from padua library in python. and it gives me the error in the question which I don't know how to deal with. Where is says enrichment that is where the error comes. Sorry I can't give you any data it comes from another processing software. But there is no problem with the data. Just the function has bugs which the creators didn't see.

```
def enrichment_from_msp(dfmsp, modification="Phospho (STY)"):
    """
    Calculate relative enrichment of peptide modifications from modificationSpecificPeptides.txt.

    Taking a modifiedsitepeptides ``DataFrame`` returns the relative enrichment of the specified
    modification in the table.

    The returned data columns are generated from the input data columns.

    :param df: Pandas ``DataFrame`` of modificationSpecificPeptides
    :return: Pandas ``DataFrame`` of percentage modifications in the supplied data.
    """

    dfmsp['Modifications'] = np.array([modification in m for m in dfmsp['Modifications']])
    dfmsp = dfmsp.set_index(['Modifications'])
    dfmsp = dfmsp.filter(regex='Intensity ')

    dfmsp[ dfmsp == 0] = np.nan
    df_r = dfmsp.sum(axis=0, level=0)

    modified = df_r.loc[True].values
    total = df_r.sum(axis=0).values
    enrichment = modified / total

    return pd.DataFrame([enrichment], columns=dfmsp.columns, index=['% Enrichment'])
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the answer is that df_r.loc[True].values has length 0 and df_r.sum(axis=0).values has length 220. Python is complaining that division isn't defined for series of different length. It seems like a data issue.

You don't have to give a real example of the data, but if you can give a fake dataset that reproduces the error, it might help prove that the issue is in the code and not in the data, which might help you get additional feedback.